# Display notification daily with AlarmManager and Service

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

I want to daily display a notification, however the notification is displayed every other now and then. So far I haven't figured out the pattern.

In my `MainActivity#onCreate` I execute this code for starting it:

```
final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);

final AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, getPendingIntentForDailyReminderService(context));
```

For stopping the AlarmManager I have this code (it's only executed when the user changes the preference):

```
final AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.cancel(getPendingIntentForDailyReminderService(context));
```

The function `getPendingIntentForDailyReminderService` is defined as follow:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(context, DailyReminderService.class);
return PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

And this is my Service class:

```
public class DailyReminderService extends Service {
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(final Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int flags, final int startId) {
        final String contentText = this.getString(R.string.daily_reminder_text);

        final NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder.setContentTitle(this.getString(R.string.app_name));
        builder.setContentText(contentText);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_icon);
        builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(contentText));

        final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        final Notification notification = builder.build();
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);

        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Also I've registered the service in my Manifest:

```
<service
    android:name=".dailyreminder.DailyReminderService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to do this would be to use a `BroadcastReceiver` rather than a `Service`.

If you return `START_STICKY` from the `onStartCommand` and never explicitly stop the service, every time the service is killed due to low resources, the OS will try to restart the service at a later time when it has the resources to do so.

Comment: So my code in `Service#onStartCommand` would then go into `BroadcastReceiver#onReceive` ?

Comment: @Niklas Yes, for the most part.